# Is it required to have concurrency control in the DAO class of the Web Application?

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, dao

I have a simple web application built on Servlet and simple DAO classes to handle database (MySQL) operations.

My servlet may receive multiple requests at the same time. How will the database handle multiple requests?

Suppose I have an "item" database table. Multiple requests may update or delete from the "item" table at the same time.

Is it required to use [Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) and [lock](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-table-locking) the table explicitly during update and delete operations in the DAO class, or will concurrency be handled by the database automatically?

Comment: I recommend reading about [ACID (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and [isolation levels (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)). --- As I see it, the question is not really about java, but DBMS and most probably off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: This question will most likely get closed as opinion based, but in general, reads don't need transactions.  Transactions are needed for writing (insert, update, delete) operations and transactions are normally handled by the Service Layer.  I would look into application layers (UI, Services, DAO/Repositories) and go from there.  Good luck.

Comment: @hooknc everything is transactional. If we do not create an explicit transaction, an implicit one is created.

Comment: What database technology are you using? A flavor of SQL?

Comment: @Turing85 thank you for the correction.  I have to admit that some of my transaction knowledge is a bit shaky, but I could see there always being a transaction.

Comment: @TylerH, I am using MySQL.

Comment: Note that it is important to avoid opinion-based language like "should I"--opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.